# WCF and API communication is creating a deadlock (httpClient)

Tags: wcf, deadlock, dotnet-httpclient

We have a service API (SERVICE) in .netcore 6,  a Wcf Services (WCF) in .netframework 4.7.2 and a gateway API (GATEWAY) in .netcore 6. It acts as a gateway to access WCF services

The use case is the following:

```
1. GATEWAY calls(wcf) WCF/Admin.svc to perform a task
                   2. WCF/Admin.svc calls(api) SERVICE to perform a part of the task
                                            3. SERVICE calls(api) GATEWAY to get some permission info
                                                               4. GATEWAY calls(wcf) WCF/Admin.svc to have the permissions info
```

calls are stuck on the 4. request.
All calls are async, there is no call to `.Result`

Case 1

We use a shared `HttpMessageHandler` to connect WCF (using [this kind of approach](https://medium.com/trueengineering/realization-of-the-connections-pool-with-wcf-for-net-core-with-usage-of-httpclientfactory-c2cb2676423e).)

The workflow goes well the first time we execute the workflow.

However, when we call it a second time, the workflow gets stuck. The fourth request is never sent, until timeout of the request 3.

Case 2

We use a new `HttpMessageHandler` for each request (which is a bad practice).
All goes well, all the time.

My guesses

I think that we have either:

- a request queuing in the `HttpClientHandler` (which I doubt)
- a synchronization lock in the `httpClient` because we have reentrant call that uses the same `HttpMessageHandler`
- There is a throttling mechanism in WCF that activates when using the same `HttpMessageHandler` for reentrant requests

Can we be aware that a call is reentrant?

Comment: As far as I know, WCF Service default to single threaded. All calls and callbacks are encapsulated into a single process. Change the value of **UseSynchronizationContext** to **false** : `CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)`.

Comment: Hello @Jiayao thanks for your comment.
It didn't help, but I will give the answer right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered what was happening:

In order to make usage of the `HttpContext` (and other Asp.Net integration) we use the `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]` attribute value.

However this creates a side effect - which in our specific case we are not interested in -, that is creating a ASP.Net `Session`.

Upon dong this reentrant loop, asp.net detects that the session is the same and will **lock** this session state until the first query is over.

So to make this work, I have added this configuration in the `Web.config`.

```xml
<system.web>
 <!-- [...] -->
        <sessionState mode="Off"></sessionState>
 <!-- [...] -->
</system.web>
```

Now all is working perfectly.